# Looking to display records from Table A that have more than one relationship to Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

This sounds like a very simple query but I have never needed this calculation before. I'm using SQL Management Studio and SQL Server 2008.

I have a table **ct_workers** which contains individual employees and a second table cs_facilities which shows the sites that they work at.

The table ct_workers has a field **person** which is the primary ID for each employee and has a field **facility** which links the employees to **cs_facilities** via a field **guid**

I'm looking to display all workers that have 2 or more facilities.
I've though about using Excel or rownumber but surely that must be a simple efficient way of doing this?

Can anyone assist please?

Thanks,

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`

```
SELECT cw.person
FROM ct_workers cw
GROUP BY cw.person
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cw.facility) >= 2
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working. I should have clarified that 'person' is the field associated with every home the employee works in, the field 'employee' is unique for each home they work in.

Comment: @matt80 - sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests that you can use aggregation:

```
select w.person
from ct_workers w
group by w.person
having min(w.facility) <> max(w.facility);  -- at least 2 values
```

However, if the `person` is the unique key in `ct_workers`, then a person can only be in one facility.  So, your question would not make sense.  You should actually have a junction table with one row per person and per facility.

Comment: Thanks but the code isn't working. Can you clarify how a junction table can be constructed from these two tables please?